# voltage division resistor value choice and battery terminals

Tags: batteries, resistors

lets say I want to divide my voltage by 2. For this reason, I must use 2 identical resistor for voltage divider curcuit. I must either use 1ohm resistors or 100000000k resisitor if there is such thing. As long as my input voltage drops to its half, what is up with resistors values

what happens if positive terminal of a battery is connected to soil. would there be current flowing into the soil?

Comment: One question per posting please, edit one of them out, and ask it in a separate posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As long as my input voltage drops to its half, what is up with
>   resistors values?

It is a matter of how much current flow you want, or can tolerate. With a 12 volt battery 2 each 1 ohm resistors is 2 ohms, so 6 amps of current will flow. 12*6 = 72 watts of power, wasted as heat.

With 1 K resistors things get much better. Only 6 mA of current flows for 72 mW of heat. Whether it is grounded or not does not affect current flow.

You must have some use for 1/2 the battery voltage, so decide based on what current your load consumes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking for a duplicate of this question, but I couldn't find one. So here it goes.

> lets say I want to divide my voltage by 2. For this reason, I must use 2 identical resistor for voltage divider curcuit. I must either use 1ohm resistors or 100000000k resisitor if there is such thing. As long as my input voltage drops to its half, what is up with resistors values

Sure, you can use 1 Ω resistors, or 100000000kΩ resistors. But the power dissipated in the resistors are different.

With 1 Ω resistors the following will happen:

- two 1 Ω resistors will have 4.5 A flowing through them
- 9 V × 4.5 A = 40.5 W
- 20.25 W per resistor, this will heat up to dangerous temperatures in seconds.

With 1 MΩ resistors the following will happen:

- two 1 MΩ resistors will have 4.5 µA flowing through them
- 9 V × 4.5 µA = 40.5 µW
- 20.25 µW per resistor, this is not even noticeable.

So if the 1 MΩ reduces the wasted power, then why don't we use them all the time?

Noise and loading is the reason, if you connect a 1 kΩ resistor in parallel with the 1 MΩ resistor that is connected from ground to the 4.5 V node, then you will bring the 4.5 V node down to ~1 mV. That is far away from the wanted 4.5 V. If you do the same but with 1 Ω resistors instead of the 1 MΩ, then you will have ~4.49 V which is very close to the original 4.5 V

Regarding the noise, just imagine all the RF signals flowing through the air, human made and from stars, lamps and other random sources, some of them will enter your circuit. These can be visualized as current sources on random places in your circuit. Also, don't forget that there are parasitics everywhere, like inductances and capacitances everywhere. So there's a capacitor in parallel with the 4.5 V node. And we have 1 µA flowing from.. let's say into the 4.5 V. Some will enter the capacitor, some will go through the resistor down to the ground, some will go upwards. What you end up with is a 4.5 V node +- error. with 1 MΩ resistors, the error will be greater, with smaller resistors the error will be smaller. So the signal to noise ratio will be better with smaller resistors

So a typical value for resistors that are not too small to waste power like crazy, and not too small to be susceptible to noise. And not too weak to load them with op-amps or other devices that may take some small currents are resistors in the range between 1 kΩ and 100 kΩ. But what you actually use will depend on your specific circuit, but if you end up using 300 Ω or 300 kΩ then you should see a red/orange flag that they are outside of the range.

> and also I wonder lets imagine a circuit with multiple batteries and must current from one of those batteries positive terminal return to negative terminal of the battery by which it is created or can that current go to some other negative terminal of some other battery?

In reality, electron wise it doesn't matter. The current will be joined and then split up, you can't choose that the electron goes into one branch or another. So if you have two batteries, then some of the current from one battery, will in reality, end up in some other battery, and vice versa.

But I don't think you understand what I'm saying to this question, because this question is so *weird* that I think that I might misunderstand you.

Mathematically every battery has one current and every electron that exits the battery is magically entered back into the battery. Even if you have several in parallel. Because when you set up [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) loops you will see current flowing through the loops, and done properly you will see that there is one per battery source.

You can't make perpetual machines or "weird physics", so I strongly advice you to properly read books or go the university or watch some [Dave Jones videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f-2yXiYmRI). Also don't forget that you can [simulate circuits](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) and learn through that way.

> what happens if positive terminal of a battery is connected to soil. would there be current flowing into the soil?

There would be no current flowing. You need to complete a circuit for current to flow. Complete means having a return path. The negative end of the battery is unconnected. If you connect a battery to a purely resistive circuit, then you will have current coming out of the battery's positive terminal and going back into the battery's negative terminal. This is with the conventional flow of electrons.